# are these wildcards redundant?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I have two examples of methods that uses wildcard generics.

First example:

```
public static <T extends Comparable> T findMax(List<T> list)
```

Second example:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T findMax(List<? extends T> list)
```

I want to know if these two examples are redundant. If yes, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two examples are telling you different things, so they are not redundant, they give different information and restricts the type in a different way.

```
public static <T extends Comparable> T findMax(List<T> list)
```

In this example, you are telling your `T` variable can be of any type that implements or extends `Comparable` (if it is a class or an interface)

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T findMax(List<? extends T> list)
```

In this example, you are telling that the `T` type should extends comparable and also telling that the type must be a super class of `T` (inside comparable) but it can be a sub-type of `T` in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Both wildcards make a difference.

The first one says that T or a supertype of T must implement the Comparable interface. The second one says that you can use a List of objects of type T or of subtype of T.